# Eclipse version confuses me

Tags: eclipse

When I check the version of my Eclipse, it looks this:

[image]

But when I start my Eclipse, its splash screen shows this:

[image]

I am confused. My Eclipse is version 2019 or version 2021?

**NOTE：**

I remember I installed the Eclipse in 2019. After that, I didn't do any manual updates.

**Installed Software**:

[image]

Comment: Did you update Eclipse or did you do a fresh install?

Comment: @GinésRuiz fresh install in 2019, then no manual updates and installations.

Comment: If you click "Installation Details" on the About, what does it show "Installed Software"?

Comment: @greg-449 please see my update above

Comment: Everything in that list has 2019 build dates and looks consistent with 2019-12. No idea where the splash screen is coming from.

Comment: As greg-449 already said, everything except the splash screen looks like 2019-12 (4.14). Theoretically, an installed plugin can set a different splash screen. A different splash screen can also be set manually. Show your `eclipse.ini` and `configuration/config.ini` for more information. Consider reinstalling the current version of Eclipse from scratch.